Copy Normals Of Multiple Faces?
as you may know this is the output of Alt + N >> Copy Vectors with multiple faces selected..

the goal is, having a given object with bad shading and an exact copy of it with good shading, to workaround copying normal data of each face in the object-copy and paste it on the equivalent face in the original object.
data transfer is made for this work but..
data transfer sometimes just acts up for me for some reason like shown,

and besides it takes longer to set up compared to Alt + N click click...
there was a git addon called TINA that does this but it's deprecated afaik.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.
